# RavenDB map/reduce index performance for bulk insert of 3 million records

Tags: mapreduce, ravendb

I am currently using RavenDB in a proof-of-concept for a simple dashboard application that provides an aggregated view over incoming events into a system. Lets say for example the user can see a granularity of by hour (for a day), day, month or year.

I have 3 million existing events to import & index and I'm looking for the best / most performant way to go about doing this after a number of less than successful attempts.

Please note this question isn't about the performance of the application once the data and indexes have been generated, that part is very good.

So I have:

- A single class that represents the events, with fields for what happened and when (DateTime + 3 string fields).
- Map/Reduce indexes for Hour, Day, Month and Year based on then event date and event type.
- The app queries the indexes for the hourly, daily, monthly and yearly values
- Historically the hourly aggregates would needed at minimum (not the individual events).

I can import the data without issue provided the indexes don't exist, however if the indexes exist i consistently get OutOfMemoryExceptions after about 45 minutes of index processing.

Can the indexing process be tweaked and what would be the suitable values?

Alternatively happy to have it suggested to approach the problem from a different way.

Comment: Is your process running as 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: Matt, its 32bit tested on both Win2k3R2 & Win2k8R1

Comment: RavenDB doesn't work well with 32-bit, but you can tweak some settings to make it work better. See http://ravendb.net/docs/faq/low-memory-footprint and http://ravendb.net/docs/server/administration/configuration

Comment: BTW what build are you using?

Comment: Thanks Matt, I've been using the latest stable 960

Comment: I'm trying the process again on a 64bit 2k8r2 with 8Gb ram...

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue on the 64bit machine as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found that separating the import process into batches (say all data for one month at a time), importing with the indexes existing in raven and then waiting until there were no longer any stale indexes produced the most stable results.

I used the GetStatistics().StaleIndexes combined with a Thread.Sleep to have the process wait between batches. I still had the session batch size left at 1024 documents per session.